# Connection string to SQL by EntityFramework and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I write web page in MVC, which use Entity Framework as ORM mapper. I put my connection string to web.config file. Here is it:

```
<add name="JP_CMS" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=JP_CMS;
User Id=CmsWebUser;Password=abcd1234abcd1234;"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I try to get data by this C# code

```
    public DataBaseContext()
        : base("JP_CMS")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DataBaseContext>());
    }

//------------------------------

    var db = new DataBaseContext();
    var result = db.Articles.ToList(); //<- here is thrown exception
//------------------------------
```

My local SQL server is running, this table is exists, but I get excepion like in this:

[image]

I think it is the most important expection: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

Could you help my by give some idea what I make wrong?

Comment: The exception image is not helpful. Please mention the valid exception. Did you derive DataBaseContext class from ObjectContext class? It doesnt look so.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a specific instance?

Comment: I try to get my own local SQL Server

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? also, are you using `Data Source=.` in the connection string?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to this server (. means local server) using SSMS from the machine where the code is running? Does it give the same error?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database using the same connection setup (Data Source & User) in the SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi Error indicates EF tried to connect to the server but failed.

Could you Checkk,

1) SQL Server should be up and running.

Go to All Programs >> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 >> Configuration Tools >> SQL Server Configuration Manager >> SQL Server Services, and check if SQL Server service status is “Running”.

In addition, ensure that your remote server is in the same network. Run “sqlcmd -L” in your command prompt to ascertain if your server is included in your network list.

2) Enable TCP/IP in SQL Server Configuration

For more info you can go [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/)

Answer (score 2):

"The system cannot find the file specified" error. Check carefully your connection string.

Comment: I think taht problem is in my connection string, but I have no idea where. It's possibe that EF have problem when db must be recreated and I specify login and password do access db?

Comment: Can you write your SQL server version?

Comment: Specify data source like this Data Source=.\SQLExpress Also check, is your server is turn on, is the user name and a password are correct, is data base with name "JP_CMS" exists on yours SQL Server instance. And check is user "CmsWebUser" has permission to work with data base "JP_CMS"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `DataSource =.` try `DataSource = .\sqlInstanceName`. Also `DataSource=(local)` might work.